# Error on Stripes

Tags: java, stripes

I got this page:

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource () is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.11
```

This is what appeared on console:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter StripesFilter
```

I followed this diligently, what could I have forgot? http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Quick+Start+Guide

I'm using Tomcat 7.0, Java 1.6.0_24, using Dynamic Web Project under Eclipse, this is my Eclipse version:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Helios Service Release 1
Build id: 20100917-0705
```

If it has a bearing, I'm using Mac OS X

Detailed error message:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter StripesFilter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.util.Log.getInstance(Log.java:43)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter.<clinit>(StripesFilter.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5215)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually issues like this are caused by either an incorrect web.xml file, or by a required JAR file not being on the classpath.

If you check Tomcat's log directory (should be under CATALINA_HOME/logs) you should find some log files named '<hostname>.<date>.log' (for instance, "localhost.2011-03-18.log").  In the current log file you will likely be able to find a stacktrace that will provide a lot more detail about the exact cause of the error.

Comment: I drag the stripes.jar from Finder(Mac's Windows Explorer) to WEB-INF/lib, it didn't work. I also tried "Import..." and selected Archive file, but it didn't work too.

Comment: Judging by your stack trace, you are missing 'commons-logging.jar'.  If you find this file and copy it into WEB-INF/lib it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Copy commons-logging.jar to your /WEB-INF/lib dir

Regarding to your link:

> For deploying and running Stripes you
>   will also need to copy the following
>   library files supplied with Stripes
>   into your classpath:
>
> ```
> * commons-logging.jar (1.1)
> ```

Comment: More info under the requirements section on the Stripes download page, http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Download